# How to uppercase and convert data to ArrayList in Robot framework?

Tags: selenium, robotframework

I had to create a robot framework script for comparing data between Excel and WebDriver (Firefox).

Solution 1: The problem is "I cannot convert to uppercase and convert to ArrayList for comparing data".

```
${doc1}=   Open Excel Document        filename=${OpenExcel}     doc_id=doc1
${view_bicccicmdu}=   Read Excel Row    row_num=1   max_num=6   sheet_name=UpperTT
${view_bicccicmduCheckLength}=    Get Length    ${view_bicccicmdu}
Wait Until Page Contains Element    ${EmptyValue}  ${timeout}
Click Element   ${EmptyValue}
Execute JavaScript  window.scrollTo(0, 7000);
Wait Until Page Contains Element    ${ClickAV.CheckColumn}  ${timeout}
${HG}=          Get Text    ${ClickAV.CheckColumn}
${UPPER1}=      Evaluate     "${HG}".upper()
${HG2}=         Combine Lists  ${HG}
${HGLenght}=         Get Line Count  ${HG}
Should Be Equal     ${HGLenght}    ${view_bicccicmduCheckLength}
Should Be Equal     ${HG}     ${view_bicccicmdu}        ignore_case=True
Close Excel Document
```

Solution 2: The problem is "I cannot convert to uppercase".

```
${doc4}=   Open Excel Document        filename=${OpenExcel}     doc_id=doc4
${view_callsrc}=   Read Excel Row    row_num=5   max_num=6   sheet_name=UpperDD
${view_callsrcCheckLength}=    Get Length    ${view_callsrc}
Wait Until Page Contains Element    ${EmptyValue}  ${timeout}
Click Element   ${EmptyValue}
Execute JavaScript  window.scrollTo(0, 7000);
Wait Until Page Contains Element    ${ClickAV.dropdownSeID}  ${timeout}
#Execute JavaScript   ${ClickAV.dropdownExJ}
Wait Until Page Contains Element    ${ClickAV.dropdownExSelect}  ${timeout}
${HG}=   Get List Items    ${ClickAV.dropdownExSelect}
${UPPER1}=      Evaluate     "${HG}".upper()
${HGLenght}=    Get length    ${HG}
# ${BBB}=     Strip String    ${HG}   characters=total
#${BBB2} =  Convert To Integer  ${BBB}
Should Be Equal     ${HGLenght}    ${view_callsrcCheckLength}
Lists should be equal     ${HG}     ${view_callsrc}
Close Excel Document
```

Solution 3: The problem is "I don't know how to ignoreUppercase or ignoreLowercase, I just need to compare the data that are equal".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set Both of the Lists to lower case, just before you check if they are equal to make sure The lists are incasesensitive.

```
${HG_LowerCase}=    Evaluate     "${HG}".lower()
${View_callsrc_LowerCase}=    Evaluate     "${view_callsrc}".lower()
Lists should be equal     ${HG_LowerCase}     ${View_callsrc_LowerCase}
```

Comment: @Phatto So if one list is missing a Char example "," it will always fail as they are not equal.

Comment: Can I using .lower() with array(list) variable?

Comment: I would suggest you to use A custom Keyword to change That type to an list or what ever type you want.

Comment: @Temizzi I had to edit my ${HG} to "Get Text" and create "@{Array1}=  Split String ${HG}   \n"  so It's work now, Sorry for the delayed response.

Answer (score 2):

In order to convert between UPPERCASE and LOWERCASE, then you can use & import the **STRING** Library in ROBOT Framework (standard library, not need to install). Refer to this link: https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/String.html .

In regards to converting data to array/list, then you need to use the **COLLECTIONS** library (standard library). Refer to this link: http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/Collections.html

1.To convert to uppercase in ROBOT Framework, we can do like below..

```
${str1}=  Convert To Uppercase  abc
${str2}=  Convert To Uppercase  1a2C3d
Should Be Equal   ${str1}   ABC
Should Be Equal   ${str2}   1A2C3D
```

2.To create a new list and append new values to list, then you can do like below..

```
${output_list}=  Create List  # if no arugment is given, then an empty will be created
Append to List ${output_list}  ${new_item1}  ${new_item2}   ${new_item3}
```

3.In order to compare two(2) different lists, you need to convert both lists first to either uppercase or lowercase (because 'abc' != 'ABC', then you can use the code below..

```
List Should be Equal  ${list_1}  ${list_2}
```

I see that you use COMBINE LISTS keyword. This keyword is to combine several different list into a single list like below. Let's say you already have 3 lists as ${list_1}, ${list_2} and ${list_3}, then..

```
${new_list}=  Combine Lists  ${list_1}  ${list_2}  ${list_3}
```

Hope this helps..

Comment: I have read all of these before start coding my script. Thanks for your help.

Comment: If this is not the answer that you want, then I hope you can provide your own answer here, So that this question will become useful for others. Because If there is other solution then I would like to know that too..

Comment: This answer was helpful to me, I was looking for a keyword to do the conversion and return the result.

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays is also possible use inline evaluation for uppercaseing strings with couple of variations. Check out RF documentation [6.7   Evaluating expressions](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#evaluating-expressions)

Below one example which also works bit older versions of RF.

```
${tempHello}=    Set Variable     hello

${{'${tempHello}'.upper()}}
```